# CCAvenue PHP Integration with Form

Tags: php, ccavenue

Need help in technical implementation. Currently we have on our website drop down list to select product and then click on pay now using Paypal.

Want to implement similar in CCAvenue. Kindly advise ( created a product on ccAvenue console and got the product ID). Looked at CCAvenue documentation but didn't find any implementation similar to this.

Example of current paypal implementation

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXX">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="test">test</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="Option1"> $60.00 USD</option>
<option value="Option2">$160.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After Creation of account in ccavenue, you can get shopcart values, currency and valid url through which you can post this.
Below is sample code for reference

```
        <form name="linkForm" method="POST" action="" id="form">
          <select name="mydropdown" class="styled" onchange="document.getElementById('form').setAttribute('action', this.value); document.linkForm.submit(); ">
            <option value="https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/txn/shopcart/XXX,XXX,INR,http://yoururl.com">Select Option</option>
            <option value="https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/txn/shopcart/
    YYY,YYYY,INR,http://yoururl.com">Option 1</option>
           <option value="https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/txn/shopcart/
    YYY,YYYY,INR,http://yoururl.com">Option 2</option>
<option value="https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/txn/shopcart/
    YYY,YYYY,INR,http://yoururl.com">Option 3</option>
          </select>
        </form>
```

Comment: I need help regarding redirect to CCAavenue payment, I have value like getting from a customer using some PHP logic, now to how to redirect payment gateway with my value. Eg.  my code:  www.bit.ly/2UOzzSo

Comment: @Gem - not sure.. try asking a question so someone will guide